# How do you communicate with a military drone operator over radio?

Tags: radio-communications, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

[This article](https://www.aljazeera.com/amp/news/2019/07/warship-destroys-iranian-drone-strait-hormuz-190718192635252.html) (and other similar ones) states:

> In remarks at the White House on Thursday, US President Donald Trump said the drone had flown to within 1,000 metres of the USS Boxer and had ignored "multiple calls to stand down".

For airplanes, ICAO standardizes 121.5 MHz and 243.0 MHz (military) as common emergency frequencies that aircraft "should" monitor when possible. If approached by an unknown aircraft, this is the frequency I'll try to raise the crew on first.

How does this work for drones? Does the same standard apply? Is it reasonable that in this case the USS Boxer's crew could expect that the drone is monitoring 121.5 (or 243.0) and that its operators will be listening?

Comment: Very interesting question !

Comment: In the same way the USS Vincennes communicated with IAF655?

Comment: @AEhere The political aspect is totally out of scope and irrelevant to my question. IAF655 was a crewed commercial aircraft; I'm specifically asking about unmanned aircraft (drones).

Comment: Also to be totally clear, I'm asking about general practices and **not** this specific incident.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31309/62)

Comment: There is an obvious likely reason why Donald Trump said this, and the quotes around it indicate what the reporters think that is.

Comment: @DJClayworth I tried to be clear that I'm not remotely interested in discussing the political dimension or in answers related to same. My question is strictly about aviation and stands on its own. The background material provided is there only to provide context. I'd encourage anyone interested in the politics to visit politics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It is unlikely that a drone will monitor 121.5 or 243.0. But making calls on those frequencies would have established the likelihood that the approaching aircraft was not an innocent manned civilian craft, and increasing the likelihood that the USS Boxer was justified in attacking it.

Comment: @TypeIA perhaps it would be be best just to remove the reference to this incident from your question? I was able to answer it without clicking the link nor having heard of this recent event, so it's probably not necessary and maybe just distracting since you are explicitly looking for a general answer.

Answer (score 5):

Some UAVs carry VHF or UHF airband radios to communicate with air traffic control and other aircraft. The voice channel is relayed to and from the remote pilot operator via satellite or another form of datalink. I've heard UAVs taking with Joshua Approach in the Mojave Desert, and one time Joshua called one out to me as traffic and vice versa. I agreed to maintain visual separation, the remote pilot acknowledged and overall it was very similar to dealing with any other aircraft.

I have no idea whether they monitor 121.5 as well as whatever enroute frequency they're using, but it seems plausible that they could.